# Unbinding jQuery event handlers

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I have two event handlers of the same type bound to the same object. Here's an example of the `mousemove` event being bound to the `window` object.

```
$('body').on('mousedown', '#uiScrollbar', function(e) {
    var uiWidth = ui.width();
    var mouseStart = e.pageX;
    $(window).mousemove(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var pixelsMoved = mouseStart - e.pageX;
        ui.width(uiWidth + pixelsMoved);
    });
}).mouseup(function() {
    $(window).unbind('mousemove');
});
```

So now let's say I add another `mousemove` event to the window for something entirely different. Obviously,`$(window).unbind('mousemove')` is going to unbind both event handlers. I know that in raw JavaScript you can assign the `addEventListener()` method to a reference variable, and then just use that to remove the event listener, but I can't seem to find any documentation on how jQuery supports the use of a reference variable.

Am I missing something really simple?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var handler = function() {
  alert( "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog." );
};
$( "#foo" ).bind( "click", handler );
$( "#foo" ).unbind( "click", handler );
```

Comment: The same applies to the .on method.

Comment: This helps. I guess my issue was that I was passing an anonymous function as an argument, versus defining a function. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [.off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/), like

```
$('body').off('mousedown', '#uiScrollbar')
```